# shared context:property-placeholder in spring application

Tags: spring

I have a Spring application which a resource (*property-placeholder*) isn't shared across my spring contexts.
I've defined the *ContextLoaderListener* in my **web.xml**, and it loads a **root-context.xml**, where is defined a *<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file.properies" />*
Then my application have a portlet in it, and when I try to use some property which is defined in **file.properties** in the **myportlet-context.xml**, spring can't find that value.
Have I missed something to do?
Aren't the resources defined from the ContextLoaderListener shared across all the contexts?

Comment: can you give some more details?

Comment: I have a very similar problem too. I load properties in the root application context. In the dispatcherservlet's application context, I perform component scanning of a @Controller annotated class whose member String needs to be injected with a property value. However, this works only when I load the properties from the dispatcherservlet's context and does not work when loaded from the root application context. Any reason for this behavior?

Comment: I think that the properties aren't inherited in child contexts

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to load the `<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:file.properies" />` in dispatcher servlet..